# smartctl 6.6 missing attributes table

Tags: smartctl

I'm used to analyze the output of `smartctl -A` using `grep` on specific attributes. Example:

```
smartctl 5.41 2011-06-09 r3365 [x86_64-linux-3.2.0-4-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-11 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   078   063   044    Pre-fail  Always       -       82584316
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   097   096   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       31
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   036    Pre-fail  Always       -       4
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   084   060   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       4559064434
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   059   059   000    Old_age   Always       -       36412
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       24
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   066   057   045    Old_age   Always       -       34 (Min/Max 33/43)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       20
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       2521
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   034   043   000    Old_age   Always       -       34 (0 13 0 0)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x001a   114   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       82584316
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       242167436053925
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       1025335933
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       2789359564
```

I have a new server that does not output the attributes table. Example:

```
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-4.9.0-3-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
Current Drive Temperature:     31 C
Drive Trip Temperature:        85 C

Manufactured in week 23 of year 2017
Specified cycle count over device lifetime:  50000
Accumulated start-stop cycles:  17
Specified load-unload count over device lifetime:  600000
Accumulated load-unload cycles:  1028
Elements in grown defect list: 0

Vendor (Seagate) cache information
  Blocks sent to initiator = 650467008839680
```

Where is the table gone??
How can I make it show?
Or what is the new way to analyze it?

Thanks for your help.
Regards
Santiago

---

Following Michael Hampton question, here is the complete output of smartctl -a in the first case:

```
smartctl 5.41 2011-06-09 r3365 [x86_64-linux-3.2.0-4-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-11 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     ST500NM0011
Serial Number:    Z1M1T0H0
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 0651f7b09
Firmware Version: PA09
User Capacity:    500,107,862,016 bytes [500 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   8
ATA Standard is:  ATA-8-ACS revision 4
Local Time is:    Fri Aug 31 12:31:29 2018 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                                        was completed without error.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                (  600) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (  74) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   3) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x10bd) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   078   063   044    Pre-fail  Always       -       82654102
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   097   096   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       31
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   036    Pre-fail  Always       -       4
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   084   060   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       4559226154
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   059   059   000    Old_age   Always       -       36438
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       24
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   065   057   045    Old_age   Always       -       35 (Min/Max 33/43)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       20
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       2523
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   035   043   000    Old_age   Always       -       35 (0 13 0 0)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x001a   114   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       82654102
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       212064010276287
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       1030640949
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       2789364021

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%         1         -
# 2  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%         1         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

And in the second one:

```
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-4.9.0-3-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Vendor:               HGST
Product:              HUH728060AL5200
Revision:             A909
Compliance:           SPC-4
User Capacity:        6,001,175,126,016 bytes [6.00 TB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
Physical block size:  4096 bytes
LU is fully provisioned
Rotation Rate:        7200 rpm
Form Factor:          3.5 inches
Logical Unit id:      0x5000cca23c11809c
Serial number:        2QG9MD9X
Device type:          disk
Transport protocol:   SAS (SPL-3)
Local Time is:        Fri Aug 31 12:34:53 2018 CEST
SMART support is:     Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is:     Enabled
Temperature Warning:  Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Health Status: OK

Current Drive Temperature:     32 C
Drive Trip Temperature:        85 C

Manufactured in week 23 of year 2017
Specified cycle count over device lifetime:  50000
Accumulated start-stop cycles:  17
Specified load-unload count over device lifetime:  600000
Accumulated load-unload cycles:  1029
Elements in grown defect list: 0

Vendor (Seagate) cache information
  Blocks sent to initiator = 651482500169728

Error counter log:
           Errors Corrected by           Total   Correction     Gigabytes    Total
               ECC          rereads/    errors   algorithm      processed    uncorrected
           fast | delayed   rewrites  corrected  invocations   [10^9 bytes]  errors
read:          0        0         0         0      37886      80852.848           0
write:         0        0         0         0     172703       7066.032           0
verify:        0        0         0         0       1248          0.000           0

Non-medium error count:        0

SMART Self-test log
Num  Test              Status                 segment  LifeTime  LBA_first_err [SK ASC ASQ]
     Description                              number   (hours)
# 1  Background short  Completed                   -      13                 - [-   -    -]
# 2  Background short  Completed                   -      12                 - [-   -    -]
# 3  Background short  Completed                   -      10                 - [-   -    -]
# 4  Background short  Completed                   -      10                 - [-   -    -]
# 5  Background short  Completed                   -       5                 - [-   -    -]
# 6  Background short  Completed                   -       3                 - [-   -    -]
# 7  Background short  Completed                   -       3                 - [-   -    -]
# 8  Background short  Completed                   -       0                 - [-   -    -]

Long (extended) Self Test duration: 61354 seconds [1022.6 minutes]
```

Hope that is enough.

Answer (score 2):

Your new HGST drive is a SAS drive, not a SATA drive.

SAS drives do not provide a relatively standard table of SMART attributes as SATA drives do.

From the [smartmontools FAQ](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/FAQ#MyATASATAdriveisnotinthesmartctlsmartddatabase):

> SCSI/SAS and NVMe drives do not provide ATA/SATA-like SMART Attributes. Therefore the drive database does not contain any entries for these drives. This may change in the future as some drives provide similar info via vendor specific commands (see [ticket #870](https://www.smartmontools.org/ticket/870)).

Some vendors' SAS drives do provide similar vendor-specific functionality, as the maintainers noted in the FAQ.

Most of the *interesting* information is already present here anyway, e.g. drive temperature, error correction statistics, self-test reports. For this drive, at least, it's not likely you need any data that isn't already exposed.

Comment: I love that the patch has made no headway at all since this post was made